# Error due to the fact that the widget is full

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I ran into a problem that the content does not fit in the widget because of this, an error occurs from the overflow of the widget. Please tell me how can I solve this problem? I want only the list of languages ​​to scroll, not the whole screen. I've tried different options but haven't been able to resolve it yet. If anyone knows a solution to this problem, please let me know. I will be grateful.

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 178),
            const BackStepWidget(text: 'Select Language'),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            SizedBox(
              width: size.width,
              child: Card(
                color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 20),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                              child: TextFormField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: constants.Colors.greyLight,
                                hintText: 'Search',
                                hintStyle:
                                    TextStyle(color: constants.Colors.white),
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.search,
                                  color: constants.Colors.white,
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_voice,
                                    color: constants.Colors.white),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                )),
                          )),
                          const SizedBox(width: 14),
                          const Text('Cancel',
                              style: constants.Styles.smallBookTextStyleWhite)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 14),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                      child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
                        context: context,
                        removeTop: true,
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => Divider(
                              height: 2,
                              color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2))),
                          itemCount: language.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 9, bottom: 10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  language[index],
                                  style:
                                      constants.Styles.smallBoldTextStyleWhite,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  language[index],
                                  style: constants
                                      .Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhite,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            // ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap the listview in Expanded so it wont overflow...

Comment: And if I don't have a ListView, I only have ListView.seperated, what should I do in this case?

Comment: Is actually the same thing, if you wrap it in a Expanded you will have the same result, ListView.separated is just a factory constructor of ListView.

Comment: Added Expanded around ListView but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Change your outer column widget to Listview and also set its physics property to NevenScrollable widget. The Internal list view will remain the same.

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
        child: ListView(
          physics : NeverScrollablePhysics(),
          shrinkWrap : true,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 178),
            const BackStepWidget(text: 'Select Language'),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            SizedBox(
              width: size.width,
              child: Card(
                color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                child: ListView(
                  physics : NeverScrollablePhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap : true,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 20),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                              child: TextFormField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: constants.Colors.greyLight,
                                hintText: 'Search',
                                hintStyle:
                                    TextStyle(color: constants.Colors.white),
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.search,
                                  color: constants.Colors.white,
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_voice,
                                    color: constants.Colors.white),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                )),
                          )),
                          const SizedBox(width: 14),
                          const Text('Cancel',
                              style: constants.Styles.smallBookTextStyleWhite)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 14),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                      child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
                        context: context,
                        removeTop: true,
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => Divider(
                              height: 2,
                              color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2))),
                          itemCount: language.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 9, bottom: 10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  language[index],
                                  style:
                                      constants.Styles.smallBoldTextStyleWhite,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  language[index],
                                  style: constants
                                      .Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhite,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            // ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Comment: When I do this, the whole page slides down a little and the list of languages ​​​​still does not scroll

Comment: I have edited my code, check it if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Still same problem. The whole Card has moved to the middle and does not scroll